# Kivy: how to stop touch screen events passing through to desktop

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, touchscreen

I have a Python Kivy (v1.11.1) app on Raspberry Pi 3B+, and use touch screen to interact with the app. The touch screen events work well with the Kivy app. However the same touch screen events also pass through to the Raspbian desktop. When I hit a button in the Kivy app, the same touch event also passes through to the desktop which may hit an icon on the desktop which may make a mess to the desktop after I use the app for a while. I wonder how to stop the events passing through from the app? I only want the app to consume the events! There must be an option in the Kivy app config but I don't know what that it. Please help...

Comment: Seems like a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443845/kivy-touch-and-keyboard-events-passing-through-to-desktop

Answer (score -1):

That's what you mean? -

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
```

Comment: No, it does not help. The problem is when I hit a button in the Kivy app, the same touch event also passes through to the desktop which may hit an icon on the desktop. That is the issue.

Comment: Can you give small example of your program